# Creating A Mesh From Curve Correctly

Tags: bezier-curves

I've been modeling a helmet, recently tried adding some "Wings" to the sides of the helmet to give it some character. I created the wings using the Bezier Curve's and converted it into a mesh from curve and this is what I ended up with.[image]

The first image on the left is the wings in Object Mode. The first thing noticeable is the color difference between the helmet and the wings themselves. this was my first attempt at using the Bezier Curve, is this how they normally look when finished? The image on the right is in Edit Mode and as you can see its a bunch of elongated triangles creating the object. I intended to add detail including the actual wing separation, something to the extent of this picture.

I tried adding in loop edged but it wouldn't allow me to add them to the faces with the greatest surface area, only the width portion was able to add loop edges.

I'm curious to know if I either did something wrong or I need to do something extra on top of this? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I just tried using the Remesh Modifier to try and recreate the mesh. After applying, in edit mode the Object is black, showing no vertexs, faces nor edges.

(I had to merge 2 pictures to post)

[image]

Comment: Try to use a **Remesh Modifier** (https://docs.blender.org/manual/ja/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/remesh.html).

Comment: That is how a normal mesh converted from a curve looks. If you built them as a curve leave them as a curve. Looking at your reference image it looks like those wings will need more refinement so a curve is not the adequate object type.